# Assigning specific items in ListViewBuilder for certain values of index

Tags: flutter, listview

I have implemented a standard ListViewBuilder. My objective is to set some properties according to the index, for example if the index is equal to (item count - 1), i.e end of the list, i want Text to be displayed, i haven't been able to do that. Any help is appreciated. Here is my Code:

```
              Container(
                        height: 500,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 6,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            if (index <= 5) {
                              return ListCard().buildListCard();
                            }
                            return Container(
                                child: Text("FIN"),
                                height: 50,
                                width: double.infinity);
                          },
                        ),
                      )
```

[Output Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sW7-9CmXx_kx0Gs3QrOrIwQTrHep5AFL/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Let's going your example, if you want to show the Text widget on the list end you can follow below lines;

```dart
              Container(
                        height: 500,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: dynamicList.length,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            if (index <= 5) {
                              return ListCard().buildListCard();
                            }
                            if (index == dynamicList.length - 1) { // <-- this line your want logic
                              return Text('Your text widget'); 
                            }

                            return Container(
                                child: Text("FIN"),
                                height: 50,
                                width: double.infinity);
                          },
                        ),
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly logic in your code. Remember that index is starting from 0. So, the following code:

```
// From index 0 to index 5 (6 item)
if (index <= 5) {

}
```

will always executed because it is included all your items which is 6 in length.

So, change it to:

```
// From index 0 to index 4 excluding the 5.
if (index < 5) {

}
```

Comment: No, that part was intentional, i do need all 6 items, its just that after end, i want text to be displayed

Comment: If you meant is a compound widget, you can use `Column(children:[Text("Item"), Text("end")]);` inside else part.

Comment: I don't know any flutter, but @ישואוהבאותך is correct, it's the return in your "if" that is causing the problem. You should have something like `if (index < 5) {return ListCard().buildListCard();} return { ListCard().buildListCard(); Container(child: Text("FIN"), height: 50, width: double.infinity);}` That is, change the if to <5 and then add the `ListCard().buildListCard()` to the second return, for the last element.

Comment: Thanks, i sorted it out. it works now